# PHP Object Oriented Programming multiple queryes

Tags: php

So, i have this problem. I'm trying my best to practice object oriented programming and I've started with this semi OOP script. How it works, i have one table that's called portal_robot_error witch contains all robot errors. Then i have another main table called portal_robot_service witch is the highest level of the service. Connected to this table i have 2 more that is linked with the portal_robot_service table. These are called portal_service_robot_errorservice and portal_service_robot_changeservice witch contains the details of the service. I hope that I've managed to explain this part good enough!

This is what i want to do. When a user searches for a robot all errors and all services should end in a list ordered by date.

Example: 
User searches for robot 21.
Result:
Error 1 - Date, robot, position, error code etc.
Error 2 - Date, robot, position, error code etc.
Service 1 - Date, robot, service type etc.
Error 3 - Date, robot, position, error code etc.
Error 4 - Date, robot, position, error code etc.
etc...

As the script is now it only shows the errors, how can i show the services in the list?

Thanks in advance!

```
<?php   
elseif(!empty($query) && empty($inDate) && empty($id) && empty($dateLike)) {
$arr    = array();
$q      = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM portal_robot_error WHERE robot = '$robot'");

while($r = mysql_fetch_object($q)) {

    $m = "Robot ".$r->robot;
    $s = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM portal_service WHERE service_date >= '$this->lastService' AND service_date <= '$r->date' AND service_module = '$m' AND service_id > '$this->lastId' LIMIT 1");

    if(mysql_num_rows($s) > 0) {
        echo "SELECT * FROM portal_service WHERE service_date >= '$this->lastService' AND service_date <= '$r->date' AND service_module = '$m' AND service_id > '$this->lastId' LIMIT 1<br />";
        $z              = mysql_fetch_object($s);
        $this->lastId   = $z->service_id;

        if($z->service_type == "Errorservice") {
            $e                      = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM portal_service_robot_errorservice WHERE service_id = '$z->service_id'");
            $f                      = mysql_fetch_object($e);
            $errorservice_track     = $f->tracksensor;
            $errorservice_gripper   = $f->gripper;
            $errorservice_cover     = $f->cover;
            $errorservice_wheel     = $f->wheel;
            $service_text           = "Errorservice HIHIHIHI".$this->lastId;
            $service                = new Error($this->lastId, $z->service_date, "", "", $z->service_module, "", "", $z->service_type, $z->service_comment, $service_text, "", $z->service_user);
            array_push($arr, $service);                     
        }
        elseif($z->service_type == "Changeservice") {
            $e                      = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM portal_service_robot_changeservice WHERE service_id = '$z->service_id'");
            $f                      = mysql_fetch_object($e);
            $service_text           = "Changeservice HIHIHIHI".$this->lastId;
            $service                = new Error($this->lastId, $z->service_date, "", "", $z->service_module, "", "", $z->service_type, $z->service_comment, $service_text, "", $z->service_user);
            array_push($arr, $service);
        }
    }
    else {
        $n   = new Error($r->error_id, $r->date, $r->stoptime, $r->starttime, $r->robot, $r->rob_status, $r->position, $r->error_code, $r->observation, $r->solution, $r->downtime, $r->user);
        array_push($arr, $n);
        $this->lastService = $r->date;
    }

}   
return $arr;
}
?>
```

Comment: hard to give advice here, as we don't know much about the plentyfull variables you use here....what exactly fails? if you always get the results for the last else case, check your query for `$s`...else debug your `Error` constructor and check which values get inserted in which parameter

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay i found the solution. When we imported the data to the database something went wrong and added an \r at the end of everything. My problem was that the if($z->service_type == "Changeservice") did not hit. That was because of the \r at the end that nobody saw...

I'll read up on PDO and MySQLi :)